# Extract colors from css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors

I need to extract colors from CSS. The colors are in 3 formats:

```css
.style1 {
  color: #000;
}

.style2 {
  color: rgb(205, 92, 92)
}

.style3 {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
```

I have this script (from old webpage):
https://jsfiddle.net/fekula/54kcxu1a/5/

But I obtain only hexadecimal colors.
rgb and rgba are not shown.

Any idea or some similar javascript for extract and show hexadecimal and rgb/gba colors?

Thank you.

Comment: Is `rgb()` and `rgba()` correct css syntax when you do not even specify a property for such definition? In the 1st example you specify "color" which would be the text color of the class. In the second two, you do not.

Comment: you're right, thank you. Modified code..

Comment: You can convert hex to decimal. RRGGBB where each RR,GG,BB is a two digit hex number. I'm not sure on grabbing the "alpha" if thats not showing

Comment: From where are you planning to extract these colors? They can be inside `<style>`, or in any element's inline style, or referenced in a `<link>`.

Comment: External CSS file. copy - paste

Comment: Since you're only scanning a CSS text file, all you need is some pattern matching. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66143641/3113485).

Answer (score 0):

You can get all styles from element with `window.getComputedStyle()`
Example:

```js
let element = document.querySelector('.class');

let styles = window.getComputedStyle(element);
```

Experiment in console of your navigator is support JavaScript like Chrome and Firefox.

Get any element of page, and explore the `.getComputedStyle(...)` function properties.

- getComputedStyle just give rgb.

Other way, is use a function convert to convert to you like this:

https://www.phpied.com/rgb-color-parser-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

> Any … javascript for extract and show hexadecimal and rgb/gba colors [from a CSS file]?

You can use [String.prototype.matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) to locate all the hex, rgb(), and rgba() instances in a string of CSS rules.

```js
const cssStr = `
.style1 {
  color: #000;
}

.style2 {
  color: rgb(205, 92, 92)
}

.style3 {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
`;

const regexHex = /#[A-Fa-f0-9]*/g;
const hexs = [...cssStr.matchAll(regexHex)].flat();
const regexRgb = /rgb\([0-9, ]*\)/g;
const rgbs = [...cssStr.matchAll(regexRgb)].flat();
const regexRgba = /rgba\([0-9, .]*\)/g;
const rgbas = [...cssStr.matchAll(regexRgba)].flat();
const colors = {
  hex: [...hexs],
  rgb: [...rgbs],
  rgba: [...rgbas]
};
console.log('colors:', colors);
```